# Intermittent display artifacts in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, display, hp

I just installed ubuntu 18.04 as a dual boot with Windows OS and have a serious intermittent display issue. I see some pixelated patches in some areas, the one which recently spotted was in *VS code*. They don't reappear if I restart the program [Image for mentioned issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6m4n.png).

Edit:

```
> product: HP Pavilion Notebook (T0Z73PA#ACJ)  
>         *-display  
>            *-display 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])  
>            Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520]  
>            Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 131  
>            Memory at 92000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]  
>               Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]  
>               I/O ports at 6000 [size=64]
>               [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
>   Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
>   Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
>   Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
>   Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2   
>   Capabilities: [100] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
>   Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)  
>   Capabilities: [300] Page Request Interface (PRI)  
>   Kernel driver in use: i915  Kernel modules: i915
```

Comment: Hey, that was my bad with the irrelevant tag and some glitches. I have edited the question. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @K7AAY Done that. You can find the updated post.